# Best way to find enum from value for many enums

Tags: java, enums

I have a lot of enum.

I would like to add a generic method for all enums allowing to find the enum by the value. Just with something like that :

```
public static T getEnumFromVal(String val) {
    for (T e : values()) {
        if (e.getVal().equals(val)) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I could make the enum implements an interface, but unfortunately I am using Java 6 and I can not declare a static method :( ...

Do you have an other idea ?

Comment: You mean search among many enum types? Or in a single enum type with a getVal() method?

Comment: @aioobe Search in a single enum ;)

Comment: But what do you mean "generic method for all enums"? You mean you want a utility method that you can use for arbitrary enum types?

Comment: @aioobe Yes, one method, with the same implementation used by all enum.

Comment: What's wrong with the `valueOf` built in to every enum?

Comment: @BnJ, but what do you mean by .getVal()? It seems like you want to compare against a property. Or sohuld it be .name()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static <T extends Enum<T> & HasVal> getEnumFromVal(Class<T> enumClass, String val) {
    for (T e : enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {
        if (e.getVal().equals(val)) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

where `HasVal` is the common interface defining the `getVal()` method

Answer (score 8):

This method already exists in the Java API:

```
Enum.valueOf(Type.class, "Enum String");
```

This method also exists on all enum types, for example if you have an Enum called `Color`:

```
Color.valueOf("RED");
```

will return the enum type `Color.RED`.

[Java 6 Enum doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html)